# JSONB field indexes in SQLAlchemy declarative mappers

Tags: python, json, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a model for a Postgres table where I would like to add indexes on fields within a JSONB column. I've tried a few different approaches but haven't been able to get alembic to autogenerate the commands to create these indexes based on the declarative model.

```
class Content(Base):
    """
    Model for storing content. Content can be of different types. 
    """
    __tablename__ = 'content'
    __table_args__ = (
        Index('ix_content_owner_id', text("owner->>'id'")),
        Index('ix_content_category_id', text("category->>'id'")),
        Index('ix_content_metadata_styles', text("meta->>'styles'")),
        Index('ix_content_metadata_spaces', text("meta->>'s    paces'")),
        Index('ix_content_metadata_colours', text("meta->>'colours'")),
        Index('ix_content_data_store', text("content_data->>'store'")),
        Index('ix_content_data_tags', text("content_data->>'tags'")),
    )

    id            = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=1)
    content_type  = Column(String(64), index=True, nullable=False)
    content_id    = Column(String(128), index=True, nullable=False)
    uploader      = Column(String(128), index=True, nullable=False)
    date_added    = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), index=True, nullable=False,
                       default=utcnow_with_tz)
    date_modified = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), index=True, nullable=False,
                       default=utcnow_with_tz, onupdate=utcnow_with_tz)
    owner         = Column(JSONB, nullable=False)
    category      = Column(JSONB, nullable=False, server_default="'{}'")
    meta          = Column(JSONB, nullable=False, server_default="'{}'")
    content_data  = Column(JSONB, nullable=False)
    relations     = Column(JSONB, nullable=False, server_default="'{}'")
    comments      = Column(JSONB, nullable=False, server_default="'{}'")
    status        = Column(Integer, index=True, nullable=False, server_default="0")
    public        = Column(Integer, index=True, nullable=False, server_default="1")

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_on': content_type,
        'polymorphic_identity': 'content',
    }
```

I found this a thread which explains how to do this via the core-api (https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sqlalchemy/3ws_6orlSDY/lxS2FZR9PA8J). I've adapted that technique to declare indexes in the `__table_args__` attribute. The indexes use the literal text syntax `column->>'field'`.

Any ideas on how I could go about getting alembic to generate the commands for these indexes?

Comment: autogen is just a convenience feature.  it's [never guaranteed](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/autogenerate.html#what-does-autogenerate-detect-and-what-does-it-not-detect) to generate everything and PG's functional indexes are among what's not supported right now, because these aren't reflected by SQLAlchemy in the first place.  A warning for each index should be apparent when you run autogenerate.

Comment: Is it not possible to get alembic to use the text literals for the Index?

Comment: i dont understand the question.

Comment: Sorry, let me rephrase. Presumably SQLAlchemy needs to convert the Index object into a SQL string representation to generate the index. Since I am defining the index using a literal (eg: `text(meta->>'styles')`), is it not possible for alembic to use the literal without needing to support SQL generation for PG functional indexes?

Comment: PS: alembic does not produce any warnings when running autogenerate with the following invocation: `alembic -c alembic.ini revision --autogenerate -m "content models"`